# android start activity problem

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

I have two packages and both packages have different `Activity`. When I start to activity from first package `Imageview` to second package `Activity`. I have already declared activity in `AndroidManifest` but I got activity not found error.

Is there any idea to declared new activity for other packages?

Comment: Is this two packages within a single application?

Comment: what are your packages name and activity names.?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use implicit intent like described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

i.e. to define `BroadcastReceiver` in second `Activity` and start intent not for name but with action that `BroadcastReceiver` will catch.

Answer (score 0):

add your activity in menifest like as

> ```
>  <activity android:name=".packagename.activityname"></activity>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The root package of both activities should be the same as the `package="com.something"` property define in you `AndroidManifest`.

Example:

if you have `package="com.myapp"` you can't have an `Activity` in package `com.activities`.